# Why does Gnu sort sort differently on my OSX machine and Linux machine?

Tags: linux, osx, sort, locale, gnu

I have a OSX machine where `sort` runs GNU `sort` from coreutils 8.26 (installed from Homebrew), and a Linux machine where `sort` runs GNU `sort` from coreutils 8.25.

On the Mac:

```
mac$ echo -e "{1\n2" | sort
2
{1
```

While on Linux:

```
linux$ echo -e "{1\n2" | sort
{1
2
```

I'm aware that `sort` depends on the locale. I ran `locale` on the Linux machine, prepended each line of output with `export` and ran the resulting lines on the OSX machine before running (in the same terminal) the sort command again, which gave the same output as before.

I noticed, however, that running `locale` on the Mac doesn't show all of the lines which appear on Linux, and I'm not sure if this is related.

The locale on Linux:

```
linux$ locale
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_CA:en
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_CA.UTF-8
```

And locale on OSX:

```
mac$ locale
LANG="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_CA.UTF-8"
```

I've found that if I set `LC_ALL=C` on both machines, they both sort `2` before `{1`. But if I set `LC_ALL=en_CA.UTF-8` on both machines I have the differing output as above. Same if I set `LC_ALL=en_CA.utf8` on both machines. (`locale -a` lists `en_CA.utf8` on the Linux machine but `en_CA.UTF-8` on the OSX machine.)

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Try using only locales that actually exist. Otherwise it defaults to C, which you probably don't want

Comment: @Fox, I don't know what you're telling me. I said that `locale -a` lists the Canadian English UTF-8 locale differently on each machine, and that I'd tried both variants on both machines, and that this made no difference. I only have the Linux machine at my fingertips right now, and have tried the sort operation with every locale installed (a bunch of English variants plus C and POSIX) and `{1` always sorts before `2` here.

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your Q which combinations you've chosen. Having OS X as `en_CA.UTF-8` and Linux as `en_CA.utf8` _should_ be consistent, unless the collation rules are specified differently for some reason

Comment: I take back what I said at the end of my last comment; my loop was wrong. In fact on Linux it sorts `{1` before `2` in all locales except the C variants and POSIX, which sort it the other way around. Further, it doesn't make a difference whether I use `.utf8` or `.UTF-8`, and when running `locale-gen` the `.UTF-8` version is displayed, even though `locale -a` shows the `.utf8` version. [This](https://superuser.com/a/999151/288544) suggests they'll work the same way anyway. I'll test the Mac side of things again tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: @Fox: Trying on the Mac again. I'm setting `LC_ALL` to various different variants of English (all listed in `locale -a`) via export (`locale` then shows output as expected) and it seems to be having no effect whatsoever on `sort` or `date`, even where the same changes on the Linux machine do make a difference. Setting `LC_ALL` to `de_DE.UTF-8` *does* make a difference to `date`, but `sort` still has `2` before `{1`. Could something be wrong with my locales?

Comment: [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/81791) suggests, unfortunately without visible references, that the locales in BSD (and thus macOS) are "somewhat broken compared to those in Linux"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some digging on the same problem the other day, so let me share a technical answer.

---

On macOS, `/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE` (or `en_CA.UTF-8`, same thing) is a symlink to `/usr/share/locale/la_LN.US-ASCII/LC_COLLATE`, which is generated from [`la_LN.US-ASCII.src`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-118/usr-share-locale.tproj/colldef/la_LN.US-ASCII.src) with `colldef`. Here's the entirety of `la_LN.US-ASCII.src`:

```
# ASCII
#
# $FreeBSD: src/share/colldef/la_LN.US-ASCII.src,v 1.2 1999/08/28 00:59:47 peter Exp $
#
order \
    \x00;...;\xff
```

You can verify that the binary `LC_COLLATE` file is indeed generated from `la_LN.US-ASCII.src` by verifying checksums:

```
$ colldef -o /dev/stdout usr-share-locale.tproj/colldef/la_LN.US-ASCII.src | sha256sum
9ec9b40c837860a43eb3435d7a9cc8235e66a1a72463d11e7f750500cabb5b78  -

$ sha256sum </usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
9ec9b40c837860a43eb3435d7a9cc8235e66a1a72463d11e7f750500cabb5b78  -
```

The ruleset is easily understandable: just compare the byte values one by one. So the collation rules for `en_US.UTF-8` are the same as the POSIX locale (aka C locale). `{` is 0x7B, `2` is 0x32, so `{` comes after `2`.

This ruleset is an artifact of FreeBSD 5, synced into Mac OS X 10.3 Panther. See [`colldef` directory in FreeBSD 5.0.0 source tree](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/release/5.0.0/share/colldef). It never changed on OS X / macOS since.

---

On Linux, locale programs and data are part of `glibc`. See glibc [`localedata/locales` tree](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/tree/glibc-2.31/localedata/locales), or `/usr/share/i18n/locales` on Debian/Ubuntu. If you inspect `/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US`, you'll see that it pulls in `iso14651_t1_common` for `LC_COLLATE` rules. So it follows [ISO 14651](https://www.iso.org/standard/68309.html) rules for collation.

---

There are more details in the blog post: https://blog.zhimingwang.org/macos-lc_collate-hunt.

Comment: I wonder if you might add a conclusion -- if I'm understanding correctly you're saying the same as in @Fox's comment above, that basically the locales on BSD and therefore on MacOS are "somewhat broken compared to those in Linux".

I wonder also if there's anything that can be done. Can it be "fixed"?

Comment: You may reach that conclusion, but "broken" seems subjective since AFAIK POSIX spec doesn't mandate any locale other than C at all, let alone actual collation rules, and I haven't read Unicode specs so I can't say if Unicode mandates ISO 14651. It's unsophisticated, that much I can say, objectively.

Comment: @tremby As for can it be "fixed"? I suppose you can pluck the locale source files from the current FreeBSD tree https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/release/12.1.0/share/colldef compile and replace `/usr/share/locale/*/LC_COLLATE`, but you could very well break unknown things, so I wouldn't recommend it.